How do I stop meetup prompting me for feedback after every event?
After I attend an event on meetup.com, when I next visit the site it will prompt me with a modal that demands I give feedback. It asks 'Have you attended this event?', if you click 'yes' then it requires feedback.
It's very annoying and disruptive, there is no easy way to dismiss it except to click 'No' but that removes your RSVP, which I don't want to do.
Is there any way to disable it? I can't find anything in the options.
I do wonder why they did this - Most websites make the sane choice of optional feedback. Coercing me doesn't put me in a good mind to say nice things.
